# Manipulate existing interface / object type

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a typescript `Generic<>` that would do the following:

- Given a `Root` interface I would like to overwrite this interface
- Given a `Root` interface I would like to make any of the properties optional
- I only need to manage `shallow` / top-level properties
- The `Overwrite` interface should not allow any new properties not within `Root`

```
interface Root {
 name: string;
 age: number | string;
 hometown: string
}
```

```
interface Overwrite {
 age: number; // overwriteing the union
 hometown?: Root['hometown'] // making a property optional
}
```

Should work:

```
type RL = Generic<Root, Overwrite> // should have `name`, `age`, `hometown`
```

Should show error for `Overwrite` function because `lastName` is not in the `Root`:

```
type RL = Generic<Root,{lastName: string}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very verbose working example.

```
export type Merge<A, B> = Omit<A, Extract<keyof A, keyof B>> & B;
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
export type Overwrite<A, B extends { [K in keyof B]: K extends keyof A ? A[K] : never }> =
  Merge<Omit<Merge<A, B>, Extract<keyof A, keyof B>>, Pick<Merge<A, B>, Extract<keyof A, keyof B>>>;
```